# Degree of field extension proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I need to show if this is true or false and prove why that is the case.

$[\Bbb Z_2(\alpha):\Bbb Z_2] = 2$ if $\alpha$ is a root of $X^2 + 1 \in \Bbb Z_2[X]$

I'm not sure where to start on this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does $X^2 + 1$ have any roots in $\mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: Is $X^2+1$ irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: I think it's irreducible over $\Bbb Z_2$...

Comment: @jdminer foil out $(x+1)^2$ modulo 2.

Comment: @oiler right just realised that before you posted. forgot about the modulo 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's false, as $1$, the identity element of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a root of  $X^2+1$ $\in \mathbb{Z}_2[X]$, Hence if you consider $\alpha=1$ then $\mathbb{Z}_2(\alpha)=\mathbb{Z}_2$, hence $[\mathbb{Z}_2[\alpha]:\mathbb{Z}_2]=1$ (a contradiction).